# In App Purchase single Product ID for multiple products

Tags: in-app-purchase

I am a novice ios developer. I have a situation for IAP i.e. in my app user can add product to sell and other user can purchase that product. I want to user IAP. Is it possible to add a product ID at runtime for IAP for each product ?

and i also want to know that whether we can create a single product ID for multiple products having same price ? So that when **user_1** person purchase **product_1** of price **$1.99** then i will update the database that **user_1** has been purchased **product_1** having product id ***com.product.oneD***.

in future **user_1** can purchase **product_2** of price **$1.99** having the same product id ***com.product.oneD***.

please help me. I want to know a solution that how to set same product id for multiple products.

Thank You in advance.